# Java generics in inheritance in Android

Tags: java, android, generics, android-activity

My intention is to set create a class with this type of inheritance:

```
public class BaseActivity<T> extends <T extends Activity>
```

but of course this inheritance syntax doesn't compile. Any alternative suggestion where I can arbitrarily select a Tab or Map Activity to be the base of other Activity classes whose override behavior is necessary?

Comment: Can you elaborate using actual example for `T` and showing usage?

Comment: Sure: same code line from above where T is MapActivity or where T is TabActivity.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but you can do:

```
public class BaseActivity<T extends Activity> extends Activity
```

That's not exactly what I think you mean to express, but perhaps close?

Comment: "Close but no cigar" as they say, since T needs to be at the base. I miss the C++ syntax class BaseActivity : public T

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible in Java. You would have to write "public class MyFooActivity extends FooActivity" for all the classes you care about. Generics are compile-time-only in Java and so can't really have this role, which very much has runtime implications.

Comment: ... although, I do point out that your desired BaseActivity could only assume it's inheriting from BaseActivity, since T could be BaseActivity... so "extends BaseActivity" seems practically what you want anyway?

Comment: So as an example, I'd prefer to have the ability to do:

Comment: So as an example, I'd prefer to have
class MyActivity extends BaseActivity<MapActivity>

rather than having to declare

    class MapBaseActivity extends MapActivity
    class MyActivity extends MapBaseActivity
and then
    class BaseActivity extends Activity
    class MyOtherActivity extends BaseActivity    
    

MapBaseActivity and BaseActivity are identical except for their super which seems like bad form if there's not a Java equiv.

Comment: I guess my point is -- you couldn't write any code in your ideal desired BaseActivity that used MapActivity anyway, right? Because you want that it extends something that extends Activity, and you can't assume T is MapActivity at compile time, since it could be any subclass. So, all you can know is that you definitely extend Activity. And that's what you also get with "extends Activity". I understand what you mean and it's not the same thing, quite -- but from the compile time point of view I think it is?